# Changes to CallContext in OnShown Handler are Not Persisted

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In a `System.Windows.Forms.Form`, any modifications done to the `CallContext` in the `OnShown` override (or the `Shown` event handler), disappear after the event. For example, in the following code, when double-clicked on the form, it will show 'Starting Up!' in it's title while the data was actually modified to 'Hello, World!' when the form was shown.

If the override is applied to `OnLoad` instead of `OnShown`, double-clicking will show the message as expected ('Hello, World!').

```
...
using System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging;
...

public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        CallContext.SetData("Message", "Starting Up!");
    }

    public string Message
    {
        get
        {
            return CallContext.GetData("Message") as string;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnShown(EventArgs e)
    {
        CallContext.SetData("Message", "Hello, World!");

        base.OnShown(e);
    }
    protected override void OnDoubleClick(EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Text = this.Message;

        base.OnDoubleClick(e);
    }
}
```

Can someone explain the reason for this behaviour? (Or is it just my PC, doing it's own things?)

---

This was tried in .Net Framework 4.6.1 (Visual Studio 2015) in Windows 7 x64; Target Platform is x86 (no luck with x64 or AnyCPU); `[STAThread]` is applied to `Main()`.

Comment: The behavior is normal. When you call a method using `Form.BeginInvoke`, it uses a captured `ExecutionContext` to run the method and changes you make in `CallContext` is not visible after that. 

If you take a look at source code for `Form`, you will see `OnShown` is called in `CallShownEvent` method which is called using `BeginInvoke` in [`OnLoad`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Form.cs,4906) method and so changes in `CallContext` are local to `OnShown` method and are not visible in current context.

Comment: @reza-aghaei Got it; thank you... That's the answer... I missed that `BeginInvoke` for CallShownEvent at the end of `OnLoad`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior is normal. When you call a method using `Form.BeginInvoke`, it uses a captured `ExecutionContext` to run the method and changes you make in `CallContext` is not visible after that.

If you take a look at source code for `Form`, you will see `OnShown` is called in [`CallShownEvent`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Form.cs,03a7f2034fa8ad60) method which is called using `BeginInvoke` in [`OnLoad`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Form.cs,4906) method and so changes in `CallContext` are local to `OnShown` method and are not visible in current context.

```
public class Form : ContainerControl 
{
    ...
    protected virtual void OnLoad(EventArgs e) 
    {
        ...
        this.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(CallShownEvent));
        ...
    }
    private void CallShownEvent()
    {
        OnShown(EventArgs.Empty);
    }
    ...
}
```